# Django create a genericForeignKey with SmallUUIDField() id

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

This is my model that uses Generic Foreign Key im using SmallUUIDField for `pos_id` and `object_id`.

```
class POSRecord(models.Model):
    id = SmallUUIDField(default=uuid_default(), primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, verbose_name='ID')

    # FK to a POS integration (e.g., SquareCredentials)
    pos_content_type = models.ForeignKey('contenttypes.ContentType',
        related_name='pos_record_integration',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pos_id = SmallUUIDField()
    pos = GenericForeignKey('pos_content_type', 'pos_id')

    # FK to anything in our system (e.g., Item, ModifierList, Location)
    object_content_type = models.ForeignKey('contenttypes.ContentType',
        related_name='pos_record_object',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = SmallUUIDField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('object_content_type', 'object_id')

    # Raw JSON data from the POS api
    data = JSONField()
```

On the `POSRecord.objects.get_or_create()` method I'm passing an id that I'm getting from squareup's api, to the key `object_id` and I'm getting `ValueError: bytes is not a 16-char string`. I tried to change the `POSRecord` model `pos_id` value to `models.PositiveIntegerField()` but then got this error. `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 4JSZ539TSJ5GEIMW43FFNQXF`

```
    def sync_item(self, square_item):
        item_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Item)
        square_credential_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SquareCredential)
        print(square_item.id)
        print(self.credentials.token)
        # Fetch our opy of the POS data
        try:
            record = POSRecord.objects.get_or_create(
                pos_content_type=square_credential_content_type,
                pos_id=self.credentials.token,
                object_content_type=item_content_type,
                object_id=square_item.id,
            )
        except POSRecord.DoesNotExist:
            record = POSRecord(pos=self.credentials)

        # Update our record with the fresh data
        record.data = square_item
        print(record)
        print(record.objects)
        # Get or instantiate our own version of the object 
        item = record.object
        if item is None:
            item = Item(tenant=self.tenant)
        print(item)
        # Update our version with the POS data
        item.name = record.data['name']
        item.decription = record.data['decription']

        # Save the world.
        item.save()
        if not record.object:
            record.object = item
        record.save()
```

Comment: ShortUUID should be 22 base64 encoded characters. `4JSZ539TSJ5GEIMW43FFNQXF` is 24 characters long, so it can't be used here.

Comment: i tried to change the `shortuuid` to `models.PositiveIntegerField()` and it still gave me an error.

Comment: Yes. Because your token is not an integer either. Where did you get the token? Since it's clearly a string, why not use a CharField?

Comment: i changed it to CharField, an got this error `django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "4JSZ539TSJ5GEIMW43FFNQXF"` `LINE 1: ...t_type_id" = 11 AND "pos_posrecord"."object_id" = '4JSZ539...` i also tried to use `models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
`  then i got this error `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'4JSZ539TSJ5GEIMW43FFNQXF' is not a valid UUID."]`

Comment: You have to run a migration if you change the field type. As you can see the expected type is still uuid.

Comment: you were right i didn't migrate after changing the model to CharField. thank you for your help.